# Firestore document max write rate clarification

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas#limits), it states there is a maximum write rate of 1write/sec to any single document. **Is this limit shallow or deep?**

For instance, suppose I have the following structure:

```
users<collection>/{uid}<doc> : {
  name: "whatever",
  likes<collection>: {
    shard_0<doc>: {
      like_count: 5
    },
    shard_1<doc>: {
      like_count: 4
    },
    ...
    shard_n<doc>: {
      like_count: 4
    }
  }
}
```

Lets say my max write rate to any single like shard document is 1 write/2 seconds. Clearly as I increase the number of like shard documents, I will never go over the write limit for any one of them, however if the limit is deep and I sum them up, I will certainly go over the max write rate for the {uid} document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `likes` in your example is a subcollection, you're actually following the pattern we recommend for [distributed counters in Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters). If you were trying to represent the shards in a field (e.g. a list) on a single document, that wouldn't work out for the reason you identify.